# Реально ли организовать такой личный кабинет на WordPress либо смотреть в сторону других предложений?

Tags: wordpress

делаем функционал корпоративного сайта, где у пользователей есть возможностей регестрироваться и иметь личный кабинет. В личном кабинете они могут хранить свои данные, реквизиты и.т.п Так же у них есть баланс который редактируется лишь администратором... Но хранения всей информации зависит от самого пользователя. Возможно ли такое делать на Wordpress или это муки слезы и боль
P.S я отлично понимаю что делать из WP такая себе задача, но возможно ли это?

Comment: Конечно возможно. Это же php.

Comment: Никаких слёз и боли, довольно стандартная задача на WP.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это реализовать через плагин, используя функцию шорткод (shortcode). Эта функция служит для отображения содержимого плагина (если быть кратким). Вся информация храниться в базе данных, поэтому в создании кабинета не должно быть проблем. Все это вы можете сделать на ворпресс. Вам нужно знать также АПИ Wordpress (описание функций системы)